# Java 8 lambdas to find averages of list of maps

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How, with Java-8 streams/lambdas, can I find averages of List of maps by keys?

Example:

```
List<Map<String, Double>> users = Arrays.asList(
  new HashMap<String, Double>()
    {{
      put("weight", 109.0);
      put("height", 180.2);          
     }},
  new HashMap<String, Double>()
    {{
      put("weight", 59.0);
      put("height", 186.2);          
     }}
 );

 Map<String, Double> statistics = 
 //<MISSED CODE with lambdas> (?)

 System.out.println(statistics);
 //{weight=84.0, height=183.1)
```

With old good foreachs it's quite simple, I am wondering if that could be achieved with lambdas. The reason I need it is that I am going to use Apache Spark and Java-8 lambdas will be a more standard approach for it.

Comment: are you creating a map only for keeping 2 values?

Comment: well, in fact it's not a map but Tuple4 of scala lib. at the moment there are 4 values, so it's not the case due to forthcomming changes

Comment: @Bogdan Why are you asking for a Java solution when you're using Scala?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Regarding your (deleted) answer: it's on the right track, but it has to keep the running sums and the count n order to do the division only at the end. The identity value is (0.0, 0.0, 0). This also enables parallel merging. This is how [DoubleSummaryStatistics](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.java) works, though it's more complex because it uses compensated summation to improve accuracy.

Comment: @Flown : I am using some of Scalas libraries, not Scala

Answer (score 6):

As [Andrew Tobilko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38347167/4105457) said, you should use a proper data structure not `Map`s.

If you insist on using `List<Map<>>` then you need to `Stream::flatMap` the `Map::entrySet` and use the proper `Collector`s.

---

```
List<Map<String, Double>> users = Arrays.asList(new HashMap<String, Double>() {
  {
    put("weight", 109.0);
    put("height", 180.2);
  }
}, new HashMap<String, Double>() {
  {
    put("weight", 59.0);
    put("height", 186.2);
  }
});

Map<String, Double> statistics = users.stream().flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, Collectors.averagingDouble(Entry::getValue))
    );

System.out.println(statistics);
// {weight=84.0, height=183.2}
```